# Angular combining data from different methods

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have data coming from three different services, i would like to combine data from all services into one method

```
this.data1 = this.activity1Service.getAllMonth(); 
this.data2 = this.activity2Service.getAllMonth();
this.data3 = this.activity3Service.getAllMonth();

this.alldata =  concat (this.data1,this.data2,this.data3);
```

and call as an Observable

```
GetAllData(): Observable<Data[]>{


  return (this.alldata);

  }
```

And then perhaps do ngOnInit()

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getAllData().subscribe(aldata => this.AllData = aldata);
  }
```

I am not sure how to combine data coming from different services into one method, can anyone please help.

Comment: You can use the combineLatest from rxjs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: Or see the forkJoin, merge, and so on. It depends which approach you need for your data. Here is the list of combinations you can use: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/

Comment: That depends on what output you expect. So maybe `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `merge` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin`

> forkJoin waits for each HTTP request to complete and group’s all the
>   observables returned by each HTTP call into a single observable array
>   and finally return that observable array.

Class file

```
getAllData() {
        this.data1 = this.activity1Service.getAllMonth(); 
        this.data2 = this.activity2Service.getAllMonth();
        this.data3 = this.activity3Service.getAllMonth();
        return forkJoin([this.data1, this.data2, this.data3]);
}


ngOnInit() {

    this.getAllData().subscribe(aldata => {
        console.log(data);
        this.AllData = aldata
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you want something like this:

```
import { Observable, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  getAllData(): Observable<any[]>{
    return combineLatest([
      this.activity1Service.getAllMonth(), 
      this.activity2Service.getAllMonth(), 
      this.activity3Service.getAllMonth()
    ]).pipe(map([data1, data2, data3] => [...data1, data2, data3]))
  }
```

`combineLatest` will combine the latest emitted value from each observable, whil in the `map` you can have some logic to map the data as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the promise of multiple APIs to single response object using $q.all(), please find below code snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('app1', []);


app.factory('json',function($q,$http){
  
  return function(files){
    
    var promises = [];
    
    angular.forEach(files, function(file){
      
      var deffered  = $q.defer();
  
      $http({
        url : file,
        method: 'GET'
      }).
      success(function(data){
        deffered.resolve(data);
      }).
      error(function(error){
          deffered.reject();
      });
      
      promises.push(deffered.promise);

    })
    
    return $q.all(promises);
  }
  
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,json) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  json([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]).then(function(datas){
    $scope.a = datas[0]
    $scope.b = datas[1]
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app1" >
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <pre>{{a | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{b | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: The question is for Angular +2 and not AngularJs

Answer (score 0):

**concat** does not wait for the responses to be received from all the observables, it completes a observable and sends its response then handles the next one. hence it won't combine the responses of observables.

You can think of concat like a line at a ATM, the next transaction (subscription) cannot start until the previous completes! for more details https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

You might have to use either **forkJoin** or **zip** operator that waits for the responses from all the observables and combines them to produce the final results, for more details,

https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom